# Faster way to add dummy nodes in networkx to limit degree

Tags: python, networkx

I am wondering if I can speed up my operation of limiting node degree using an inbuilt function.

A submodule of my task requires me to limit the indegree to 2. So, the solution I proposed was to introduce sequential dummy nodes and absorb the extra edges. Finally, the last dummy gets connected to the children of the original node. To be specific if an original node 2 is split into 3 nodes (original node 2 & two dummy nodes), `ALL` the properties of the graph should be maintained if we analyse the graph by packaging 2 & its dummies into one hypothetical node 2'; The function I wrote is shown below:

```
def split_merging(G, dummy_counter):
    """

    Args:
      G: as the name suggests
      dummy_counter: as the name suggests

    Returns:
      G with each merging node > 2 incoming split into several consecutive nodes
      and dummy_counter

    """

    # we need two copies; one to ensure the sanctity of the input G
    # and second, to ensure that while we change the Graph in the loop,
    # the loop doesn't go crazy due to changing bounds

    G_copy = nx.DiGraph(G)
    G_copy_2 = nx.DiGraph(G)

    for node in G_copy.nodes:
        in_deg = G_copy.in_degree[node]
        if in_deg > 2:  # node must be split for incoming

            new_nodes = ["dummy" + str(i) for i in range(dummy_counter, dummy_counter + in_deg - 2)]
            dummy_counter = dummy_counter + in_deg - 2

            upstreams = [i for i in G_copy_2.predecessors(node)]
            downstreams = [i for i in G_copy_2.successors(node)]

            for up in upstreams:
                G_copy_2.remove_edge(up, node)

            for down in downstreams:
                G_copy_2.remove_edge(node, down)

            prev_node = node
            G_copy_2.add_edge(upstreams[0], prev_node)
            G_copy_2.add_edge(upstreams[1], prev_node)

            for i in range(2, len(upstreams)):
                G_copy_2.add_edge(prev_node, new_nodes[i - 2])
                G_copy_2.add_edge(upstreams[i], new_nodes[i - 2])
                prev_node = new_nodes[i - 2]

            for down in downstreams:
                G_copy_2.add_edge(prev_node, down)

    return G_copy_2, dummy_counter
```

For clarification, the input and output are shown below:

**Input:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

It works as expected. But the problem is that this is very slow for larger graphs. Is there a way to speed this up using some inbuilt function from networkx or any other library?

Comment: Are you trying to preserve any reachability or other properties in the graph? Do you need to maintain degrees of all the not-split nodes? In the first graph, 9 can reach 2, but not in the second graph. If you need to maintain reachability, this seems like a balanced binary tree problem.

Comment: @kcsquared thanks for highlighting.  To be precise, no I don't need to maintain reachability, I will add your comment to my question for clarification. Regarding the degrees of non-split nodes, yes they should remain the same. We don't touch their incoming/outgoing edges at all.

Comment: I'm a bit confused then about your constraints; if you don't need to maintain any reachability, you could just as well remove all the edges. Is there a way you could rephrase your question into a form like "I'd like to modify my graph to have max indegree 2, such that the property (reachability/distance/cycles of X set of vertices) is preserved, while also minimizing the (size/ diameter/ algo. speed/etc) of the resulting graph"?

Comment: 'don't need to maintain reachability' does not imply 'don't need to maintain `any` reachability'. One cannot simply remove edges which existed in the original graph. Within these dummies we can change edges as we want. These are called `dummy` for a reason. So to be specific, if node is split into 4 nodes (original node 2 + 3 dummy nodes), ALL the properties of the graph should be maintained if we analyse the graph by packaging 2 & its dummies into one hypothetical node; added this in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; the idea is similar to balancing a B-tree. If a node has too many in-neighbors, create two new children, and split up all your in-neighbors among those children. The children have out-degree 1 and point to your original node; you may need to recursively split them as well.

This is as balanced as possible: node n becomes a complete binary tree rooted at node n, with external in-neighbors at the leaves only, and external out-neighbors at the root.

[image: Spltting algorithm]

```py
def recursive_split_node(G: 'nx.DiGraph', node, max_in_degree: int = 2):
    """Given a possibly overfull node, create a minimal complete 
    binary tree rooted at that node with no overfull nodes.
     Return the new graph."""
    global dummy_counter
    current_in_degree = G.in_degree[node]
    if current_in_degree <= max_in_degree:
        return G

    # Complete binary tree, so left gets 1 more descendant if tied
    left_child_in_degree = (current_in_degree + 1) // 2

    left_child = "dummy" + str(dummy_counter)
    right_child = "dummy" + str(dummy_counter + 1)

    dummy_counter += 2

    G.add_node(left_child)
    G.add_node(right_child)

    old_predecessors = list(G.predecessors(node))

    # Give all predecessors to left and right children
    G.add_edges_from([(y, left_child) 
                      for y in old_predecessors[:left_child_in_degree]])
    G.add_edges_from([(y, right_child) 
                      for y in old_predecessors[left_child_in_degree:]])

    # Remove all incoming edges
    G.remove_edges_from([(y, node) for y in old_predecessors])

    # Connect children to me
    G.add_edge(left_child, node)
    G.add_edge(right_child, node)

    # Split children
    G = recursive_split_node(G, left_child, max_in_degree)
    G = recursive_split_node(G, right_child, max_in_degree)

    return G


def clean_graph(G: 'nx.DiGraph', max_in_degree: int = 2) -> 'nx.DiGraph':
    """Return a copy of our original graph, with nodes added to ensure
    the max in degree does not exceed our limit."""
    
    G_copy = nx.DiGraph(G)
    for node in G.nodes:
        if G_copy.in_degree[node] > max_in_degree:
            G_copy = recursive_split_node(G_copy, node, max_in_degree)
    return G_copy
```

This code for recursively splitting nodes is quite handy and easily generalized, and intentionally left unoptimized.

To solve your exact use case, you could go with an iterative solution: build a full, complete binary tree (with the same structure as a heap) implicitly as an array. This is, I believe, the theoretically optimal solution to the problem, in terms of minimizing the number of graph operations (new nodes, new edges, deleting edges) to achieve the constraint, and gives the same graph as the recursive solution.

```py
def clean_graph(G):
    """Return a copy of our original graph, with nodes added to ensure
    the max in degree does not exceed 2."""
    global dummy_counter
    G_copy = nx.DiGraph(G)
    for node in G.nodes:
        if G_copy.in_degree[node] > 2:

            predecessors_list = list(G_copy.predecessors(node))
            G_copy.remove_edges_from((y, node) for y in predecessors_list)

            N = len(predecessors_list)
            leaf_count = (N + 1) // 2
            internal_count = leaf_count // 2
            total_nodes = leaf_count + internal_count

            node_names = [node]
            node_names.extend(("dummy" + str(dummy_counter + i) for i in range(total_nodes - 1)))
            dummy_counter += total_nodes - 1

            for i in range(internal_count):
                G_copy.add_edges_from(((node_names[2 * i + 1], node_names[i]), (node_names[2 * i + 2], node_names[i])))

            for leaf in range(internal_count, internal_count + leaf_count):
                G_copy.add_edge(predecessors_list.pop(), node_names[leaf])
                if not predecessors_list:
                    break
                G_copy.add_edge(predecessors_list.pop(), node_names[leaf])
                if not predecessors_list:
                    break

    return G_copy
```

From my testing, comparing performance on very dense graphs generated with `nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(500, 0.3, directed=True)`, this is 2.75x faster than the recursive solution, and 1.75x faster than the original posted solution. The bottleneck for further optimizations is networkx and Python, or changing the input graphs to be less dense.

Comment: This is a smart solution; the analogy with suffix trees makes it very easy to understand; Also, the complexity is obvious with the recursive method, thanks again! marking accepted!

Comment: after I did a timeit comparison it is in fact slower than the implementation in the question by around 25-30%. No doubt, your solution is a crisp/standard/smart way to go about it but the speed benefit is not there. So, let us see if someone else suggests something. `disclaimer`: I removed the accepted tag so that others can see the question as not accepted answer.

Comment: for reference:  `Time taken for SO solution version 5.09  seconds
Time taken for own version 3.46  seconds` for ER graph (500,3)

Comment: @lifezbeautiful Sure, as I mentioned, I didn't do the actual indexing optimizations to get O(n), since it adds a layer of indirection and makes the code quite a bit less general. Still, that's slightly surprising. I'll try out an implementation against Erdos-Renyi(500, 3) and other large random graphs.

Comment: As a followup, is that supposed to be erdos_renyi_graph(500, .3)? I'm only seeing that version in networkx. Also, any other good random graphs to test (average density, etc)?

Comment: yes, that is true. I meant the networkx ER graph, but it doesn't matter as long as you generate some random graphs the insights should not change

Comment: @lifezbeautiful I've added the fast, optimized iterative solution. It gives identical output to the recursive solution, but builds the binary tree implicitly as an array, like you would do in a heap. It's also nearly 3x faster than the recursive solution and almost 2x faster than your for the ER(500, .3, directed) test case. I don't have ideas for further possible optimizations while still using networkx and Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is 2X faster indeed than the OP's solution, tested! accepted the answer! :)